# How to change start up type of a windows service using command line

Tags: windows, apache, command-line, service, command-line-interface

My focus is on web server.

Apache web server does install service in automatic type (`httpd -k install`)  and Apache does not provide a parameter to install service in manual type (like MySQL: `mysqld --install-manual`).

I read some about [SC](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=84961) (`C:\Windows\System32\sc.exe`) and tried to change it with SC but I couldn't. So what's the solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SC should be able to handle this, are you getting any errors?

This would set the startup type to manual for a service called 'apache' :

```
  SC \\computername CONFIG apache start= demand
```

Comment: Yes it works.  My mistake was on the part _start=demand_ which I didn't put a space after equal sign.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just apply the same purpose --CHANGE WIN SERVICE STARTUP METHOD-- on a remote machine..

```
C:\MrCMD> REG QUERY \\RemoteHostName\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WUAUServ

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WUAUServ
    Type    REG_DWORD    0x20
    Start    REG_DWORD    0x2
    ErrorControl    REG_DWORD    0x1
    ImagePath    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %systemroot%\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs
    DisplayName    REG_SZ    Automatic Updates
    ObjectName    REG_SZ    LocalSystem
    Description    REG_SZ    Enables the download and installation of Windows updates. If this service is disabled, this computer will not be able to use the Automatic Updates feature or the Windows Update Web site.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WUAUServ\Parameters
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WUAUServ\Security
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WUAUServ\Enum

┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Executed Mon 01/14/2013 14:27:15.31 │ As [MrCMD]
└─────────────────────────────────────┘

C:\MrCMD> REG ADD \\RemoteHostName\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv /V Start /T REG_DWORD /d 0x3
Value Start exists, overwrite(Yes/No)? y
The operation completed successfully.

┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Executed Mon 01/14/2013 14:29:57.72 │ As [MrCMD]
└─────────────────────────────────────┘

C:\MrCMD> REG QUERY \\RemoteHostName\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WUAUServ

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WUAUServ
    Type    REG_DWORD    0x20
    Start    REG_DWORD    0x3
    ErrorControl    REG_DWORD    0x1
    ImagePath    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %systemroot%\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs
    DisplayName    REG_SZ    Automatic Updates
    ObjectName    REG_SZ    LocalSystem
    Description    REG_SZ    Enables the download and installation of Windows updates. If this service is disabled, this computer will not be able to use the Automatic Updates feature or the Windows Update Web site.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WUAUServ\Parameters
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WUAUServ\Security
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WUAUServ\Enum

┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Executed Mon 01/14/2013 14:30:37.80 │ As [MrCMD]
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

That's all folks.. :)